# Bootstrappers that download packages over the web from Microsoft

Tags: wix, windows-installer, installshield, bootstrapper

What are the best practices for creating internet download bootstrappers that reference  Microsoft packages?

For example InstallShield has a Setup Prerequisite that can download vstor40_x86.exe from Microsoft.com through a go.microsoft.com/fwlink link ID that resolves to the download url for that EXE.   InstallShield didn't create a PRQ for vstor40_x64.exe and I need to make one.  I've found the Microsoft page that has the download links for x86/x64.exe  but I can't find an fwlink ID that resolves to the x64.

What is Microsoft's position on this?  Do they document the fwlink ID's anywhere and do they want us linking to Microsoft so that they can control the availability or is this a bad practice which is just leaching off of Microsoft?

Comment: Here's a bounty for any answer related to the topic at hand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just looked at the bootstrapper that was installed when I put Visual Studio 2010 on my machine.  It is in the SDK directory (c:\program files\microsoft sdks\windows\7.0a).  The Bootstrapper directory there contains a bunch of them, the ones you get to choose from when you create a VS Setup project and select the prerequisites.

On my machine, the package file is in vstor40\en\package.xml.  The fwlink declared there for the x64 version is

> http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=158918

Given the ready availability of these bootstrappers in VS, I seriously doubt Microsoft has any problem with you actually using them.

Comment: It didn't think to look in the MS provided bootstrapper for a better URL to vstor4 x64 so that helps a little.  Still I wish I could find something official from Microsoft that says this is a public service, here's our SLA committment and here is a table of FWLINK ID's for various things we will provide.

Comment: You are posting to the wrong web site if you are looking for an official statement from Microsoft.  Contact Microsoft directly through their support channels.

Comment: I understand but Microsoft is so known for getting the message out through unofficial channels that I was hoping this would be an easier way to ask.   Still,  just the FWLINK that you got me since I didn't think to look there was worth the bounty to me.  Thanks!