# How reliable are Microsoft redistributable download links?

Tags: windows-installer, setup-deployment, prerequisites, redistributable

How reliable are download links for Microsoft redistributables?

Should they be used when coding prerequisites for installation packages?

For example, should I use the download links found on this page when making a prerequisite for an installation package?

http://www.microsoft.com/en-au/download/details.aspx?id=13255

Comment: possible duplicate of [Bootstrappers that download packages over the web from Microsoft](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3742976/bootstrappers-that-download-packages-over-the-web-from-microsoft)

Comment: Duplicate, yes.  Off topic, no.

Answer (score 0):

FWIW, there's no easy answer for this one.  I explain it to clients and let them choose between hosting the prereq themselves or taking a dependency on an external (to them) resource.

If you are using InstallShield PRQ's there is a hybrid strategy you can take.  You can host the PRQ but not the content.   InstallShield will use the PRQ (XML) embedded or otherwise on the source media if there is no internet connection.  If there is an internet connection it'll attempt to download and override from your hosted version.   They can be the same and tell it to pull content from  say MSFT  or if the MSFT link ever becomes invalid you can then choose to host the content and override at that time.

Web downloaders have their advantages but there are is far more complexity and risk  IMO.

Comment: I thought the point of downloading the content would be not to bloat the package?

Comment: Yes. The PRQ (XML) is usually just a few kilobytes.  "Bloat" isn't always a bad thing though.  Enterprises frequently want an "offline" package so they know they have everything and can copy it around inside the LAN without downloading over and over.

Comment: Ok, but my issue is whether to include the prereq content in the package or whether to have it downloaded. If it is in the package, I don't see the point of involving any downloading since you already have it in the package.  You seem to be talking about a more complex situation.